# Switch Languages/Words/Terms in a single application deployed to multiple sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I've got an application designed to be customized and deployed per customer. Basically I want to swap out the theme, web.config and the wording on a page each time the application is deployed.

I'm using App Themes to do the theme and it works perfectly. I'm using VS's xml transforms to swap out appropriate settings/connection strings/whatever in the web.config and that works fine as well.

Now I need a solution that would allow me create a default language/word/term set and let me swap out values as necessary per deployment.

Advice, links, best practices... anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started using Slowcheetah to accomplish the same thing as the web.config transform.

```
Text.xml becomes
Text.Debug.xml and
Text.Release.xml
```

I then modify the xml documents to include the appropriate text based on the deployment.